# Installshield content files are read only

Tags: installshield, installshield-le

I have added an InstallShield Limited Edition Project to my Visual Studio 2013 solution.
There is a config.txt file in the real project. When a user installs my project, he gets config.txt as read only. When I try to change the Content File permissions, InstallShield redirects me to buy its paid version. Is there a way for me to make config.txt file writable without buying paid version? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the file writable before InstallShield builds it into the installer. Unless overridden, which you've seen is limited to the paid editions, InstallShield will typically copy the attributes of the files it includes.

Comment: I have changed ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES permissions to enabled, but still there is no change with permissions of the file generated by setup.exe.. Thanks.

Comment: @jason Read-only is often an attribute rather than a permission. Have you tried `attrib -r config.txt` or the gui equivalent?